# Positioning content relative to something else

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I have three labels in my view:

[image]

The first label is a description and as the text will be fetched from an API it varies in length.

**First question** is how do I make the description label auto-adjust its height?

**Second question** is how do I make label 1 move relative to the height of description label and also label 2 relative to label 1.

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Actually no as I'm just learning but just Googled Autolayout and it seems to be just what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the number of lines to 0 and line break mode to word wrap to make a label arbitrarily tall.  You embed all three labels in a vertical stackview and set the spacing in the stackview to distribute them with equal spacing.  Constrain the stackview to the top, leading and trailing edges of your view.  You do not need to give it a height as it will derive its intrinsic height from the labels plus the spacing.

Comment: Haven't heard of a stackview so will give it a try now

Comment: This is really good answer BUT keep in mind that it will work for iOS 9+, If your project target is lower than iOS 9 it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you should definitely take a look at autolayout:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

Answer (score 0):

**How to auto adjust height**

```
descriptionLabel.sizeToFit()
```

**How to auto adjust height in relation to another label**

```
label.frame = CGFrame(x: decriptionLabel.frame.origin.x, y: descriptionLabel.frame.origin.y + descriptionLabel.frame.size.height, width: descriptionLabel.width, height:0)

label.sizeToFit()
```

note: You might want to add some padding to the y co-ordinate otherwise it will literally start where the description label ends.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all what you want to do without writing a single line of code.

**To answer your first question** : For the description label set number of lines to 0;

**To answer your second question** You can do it with 3 simple steps using auto layout :

A) Description label: set constraints to : TOP to superview , leading space to superview , Trailing space to superview, Bottom space to **label 1**.

B) Label 1 : leading space to superview , Trailing space to superview, Bottom space to **label 2**.

C) Label 2 : leading space to superview , Trailing space to superview.

Auto layout will adjust and move desire elements based on contents.

Comment: setting the lines to 0 wont auto adjust the height it will just allow more lines and add ellipses( ... ) to the end if it's too small to fit.

Comment: @torinpitchers Maybe you're right but it ll do the job. In fact when you set auto layouts and number of lines to 0 you don't need to set size to fit.